# Loopback login with phone as username and verification

Tags: email, authentication, loopbackjs, phone-number

I've extended the User model in my loopback application, and added phone number as a login method, I use the `username` field to do this, the only deal is that on login I get the 'email not verified' error, I have my own `phoneNumberVerified` field, and have overwritten the `confirm` method to validate the token against the `emailVerificationToken` and against the `phoneNumberVerificationToken` and update the corresponding flag, I thought of overwriting the original login method to not allow login only if both `emailVerified` and `phoneNumberVerified` fields are false (not just the email) but I don't know how to actually do the login the way loopback does it (I believe it creates an `AccessToken` or something), and I'm asking for some help on how to do this, thanks XD. I can do the overwriting and validations myself I just need to know how to do the actual login without using the original `login` method, since I'll be rewriting it.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out that I actually don't need email or phone number verified validation at all on login (later on the workflow will be required, but that'll be another use case, so it's irrelevant on login to me now XD). So when I was looking on how to overwrite the `login` method I realized that all the models code it's on the node_modules folder xD

> node_modules/loopback/common/models/user.js

And found there in the `login` method a flag that validates if should check email verified or not, so on my startup script I just put this:

```
app.models.MyUser.settings.emailVerificationRequired = false;
```

That stops the email verified validation on login.

And maybe if some of you would like to override the `login` method I believe copying the whole method from the original user model up there and attaching it to your model and doing some modifications might work xD, it invokes the `createAccessToken` from the user model (itself) and that's what I believe creates the 'login', what I came to understand is that there is no "session" data, it creates an accesstoken when you successfully login, and as I've been doing just sending the token id to every request 'authenticates' your logged user.

Thanks for reading, have a nice day :)